# How to check if an array contains any value of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, array.prototype.map

I have an array of object and need to check if the any value of a second array is included within a specific field.

My array is called **cocktailList** and the field I need to check against is called "**ingredients**".

The second array is called **selectedOptions**.

The following code works perfectly when the second array has only 1 value.

Example

```
const selectedOptions = ["vodka"];
const selectedDrinks = cocktailList.filter(function (item, i) {
      if (item.ingredients.toLowerCase().includes(selectedOptions)) {
        return true;
      } else false;
    });
```

The problem occurs when I have more than 1 value in **selectedOptions**
My objective is to return TRUE if the item.ingredients contains ANY value of selectedOptions.

If I have the following:

```
const selectedOptions = ["vodka", "rum"];
```

It would only return true if the **ingredients** field contains all values of **selectedOptions**

I've tried the following solution as suggested by others

```
if (item.ingredients.toLowerCase().some((val) => selectedOptions.indexOf(val) !== -1))
```

but I'm getting an error

```
TypeError: item.ingredients.toLowerCase().some is not a function. (In 'item.ingredients.toLowerCase().some(function (i)
```

Each item is an object which contains "ingredients" field containing a string of this kind

```
 Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",
    "complete": false,
    "country": "cuba",
    "dairy_free": "",
    "description": "Made without the traditional orange liqueur",
    "difficulty": "",
    "dosage": "1½ shot(s) Tequila, ½ shot(s) Lime Juice, ½ shot(s)",
    "drinkId": "1103",
    "equipment": "Shaker, Strainer",
    "garnish": "",
    "glass": "collins",
    "ingredients": "Tequila, Lime Juice, Agave Nectar Juice",
}
```

Comment: Seems like the question is in JavaScript - please tag question.

Comment: Please show us the value of `cocktailList`. It looks like in the original code, the `item.ingredients` is a string but in the other example it is not?

Comment: @Bergi I've updated my question and included an object example at the bottom. The ingredient field is indeed a string.

Comment: Ah. You'll want to use `selectedOptions.some(…)` then, not `ingredients.….some(…)`.

Comment: @Bergi like this you mean `const selectedDrinks = cocktailList.filter(function (item, i) {
      if (selectedOptions.some(item.ingredients.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
      } else false;
    });`

Comment: No, `some` still takes a callback: `selectedOptions.some(option => item.ingredients.toLowerCase().includes(option))`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi! Works perfectly, it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `some`.

Borrowing snippet from @ikik:

```js
let cocktailListc = [{
    "ingredients": "vodka"
  },
  {
    "ingredients": "water"
  },
  {
    "ingredients": "soda"
  },
  {
    "ingredients": "rum"
  },
  {
    "ingredients": "orange"
  }
]
const selectedOptions = ["vodka", "rum", "limun"];

console.log(cocktailListc.some(item => selectedOptions.includes(item.ingredients)))
```

But will fail when

```js
let cocktailListc = [{
    "ingredients": "vodka"
  },
  {
    "ingredients": "water"
  },
  {
    "ingredients": "soda"
  },
  {
    "ingredients": "rum"
  },
  {
    "ingredients": "orange"
  }
]
const selectedOptions = ["a", "b", "c"];

console.log(cocktailListc.some(item => selectedOptions.includes(item.ingredients)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple double loop...

```js
function test() {
  let cocktailListc = [{
      "ingredients": "Tequila, Lime Juice, Agave Nectar Juice, Russian Vodka"
    },
    {
      "ingredients": "water test"
    },
    {
      "ingredients": "soda test"
    },
    {
      "ingredients": "rum test"
    },
    {
      "ingredients": "orange test"
    }
  ]

  const selectedOptions = ["vodka", "rum", "limun"];

  let check = [];

  selectedOptions.forEach(opt => {
    cocktailListc.forEach(cocktail => {
      if (cocktail.ingredients.toLowerCase().includes(opt.toLowerCase()) === true) {
        check.push(cocktail);
      }
    });
  });

  if (check.length > 0) {
    console.log(true)
     console.log(check)
  }
}
test()
```

Comment: you are assuming that the values of selectedOptions must be equal to the value of ingredients which is not the case at all. Example `"ingredients": "Tequila, Lime Juice, Agave Nectar Juice, Russian Vodka"` and `selectedOptions = ["vodka", "rum", "whiskey"]`

Comment: @Butri I just changed that min ago after seeing your edit, easy fix:  `if (cocktail.ingredients.includes(opt) === true) {`

Comment: I think we're on the right path however your solution is not returning what I need. If you check my code I'm adding the cocktail object every time there's a match therefore I don't think we should use `check.push(opt)`. Just to clarify, I need to end up with `let check = [];` containing all objects where the field ingredients contains one of the selectedOptions values.

Comment: @Butri Oh I see, but then just switch it and push `check.push(cocktail);`, `cocktail` object and not a `opt` (an option). Edited fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var selectedOptions = ["vodka"];
var cocktailList = [{ ingredients: "vodka, lemon, sugar" }];

var selectedDrinks = cocktailList.filter((cocktail, i) =>
  selectedOptions.reduce(
    (has, option) => has && cocktail.ingredients.includes(option),
    true
  )
);
```